# TypeScript Structural Type Checks - Union and Intersect Types

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript. I've been playing with union and intersection types of shapes and came across something I wasn't expecting...

If I create two shapes as follows:

```
type Person = {
    name: string,
    occupation?: string
}

type Animal = {
    name: string
    gestationPeriodDays: number
}
```

I then create a union of those two shapes and an intersection as well, like this...

```
type AnimalUnionPerson = Animal | Person

let humanzeeAllFields: AnimalUnionPerson = {
    name: "Humanzee",
    gestationPeriodDays: 60,
    occupation: "Banana Farmer"
}

type AnimalIntersectPerson = Animal & Person 

let animalIntersectPerson = {
    name: "Shape Intersect",
    gestationPeriodDays: 24,
    occupation: "Data Scientist"
}
```

I then created a simple function that takes the intersection type as a parameter...

```
function printOutIntersection(toPrint: AnimalIntersectPerson) {
    console.log(toPrint.name)
    console.log(toPrint.occupation) // With union of shapes, no need for User Defined Type Guard
    console.log(toPrint.gestationPeriodDays)
}
```

Now I can pass the `animalIntersectPerson` to the function, but cannot pass the `humanzeeAllFields` as an argument to the function even though the shapes themselves have the same fields. I expected to be able to given the structural type checking performed by TypeScript. Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a matter of fact, `AnimalUnionPerson` and `AnimalIntersectPerson` does not provide the same structure:

```
AnimalUnionPerson
- name //required
- occupation //optional
- gestationPeriodDays //Because of the union typing this is optional
```

```
AnimalIntersectPerson
- name //required
- occupation //optional
- gestationPeriodDays //in this case it's required
```

As you can see, `gestationPeriodDays` status change depending on using union typing or intersection.

Comment: I thought the way TypeScript did its type checking was structural, so it looks at the fields a variable has rather than the type you say the variable is so it shouldn't matter what the types are declared as, it's the shape the variable has.

For instance I can declare a variable of type Animal and pass that to a function that will accept Person because it has the required name field that a Person would expect. In this scenario the Animal type has no link to a Person type, TypeScript just checks that the shape of the variable can be assigned to the type the function is expecting.

Comment: @Phil The point here is that the shape isn't the same - the `AnimalUnionPerson` type isn't required to have a `gestationPeriodDays` property, but the `AnimalIntersectPerson` type is required to have that property.

Comment: Enjoying the discussion here as getting me thinking more about TypeScript and learning more. I absolutely get the difference in the declaration of the shape types here, but I thought typescript ignored the shape type a variable was declared as when checking for assignability and looked to see if the structure of the variable is assignable to the type expected and in this example it clearly is as both variables look exactly the same, although they are declared as different types.

Comment: I'm guessing that my understanding needs to change from looking at whether the structure of the actual variable is assignable to the type and looking at whether the structure of the type the variable is declared as is always assignable, regardless of the value of the variable. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Intersection type**

When you have a value of type `Animal & Person`, it means that this value is ensured to be `Animal` AND `Person`.

**Union type**

When a value with type `Animal | Person` is given, it can be `Animal` OR `Person`. It could be even both. In contrast to an intersection, there is no guarantee, that the value is `Animal` AND `Person` at the same time.

To express, that a value is either `Animal` XOR `Person`, you would use a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) (sum type).

---

Carried over to your example:

`printOutIntersection` expects an intersection type `Animal & Person`. `humanzeeAllFields` is a union type `Animal | Person`, so it cannot ensure to be both `Animal` and `Person`.

Because `Person` is not [assignable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) to `Animal` (`Animal` alone has a `gestationPeriodDays` property), it is not valid to invoke `printOutIntersection` with `humanzeeAllFields` of type `Animal | Person`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-CGjmXQ0G63CD67D6WytByzKqPoFIqlcqVe1AA)

Comment: This doesn't address the fact of structural subtyping. For example, `type A = { x: string, y?: string }`, `type B = { x: string, z?: string }`, then `A | B` is assignable to `A & B`. So it's not always the case that the union isn't assignable to the intersection. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmANFCAPyY4ElQC+AUKJFAEILJo15FlQAXtWx96zJgDcAhrigBXQvgD2hTHAA+HLigxQA5ADNly-YyZTZUIsAi4sEAMbB1UAGTbEilYQDcTIA)

Comment: Plus, I thought the way TypeScript did its type checking was structural, so it looks at the fields a variable has rather than the type you say the variable is so it shouldn't matter what the types are declared as, it's the shape the variable has. For instance I can declare a variable of type Animal and pass that to a function that will accept Person because it has the required name field that a Person would expect. In this scenario the Animal type has no link to a Person type, TypeScript just checks that the shape of the variable can be assigned to the type the function is expecting.

Comment: I'm guessing that my understanding needs to change from looking at whether the structure of the actual variable is assignable to the type and looking at whether the structure of the type the variable is declared as is always assignable, regardless of the value of the variable. That makes sense.

Comment: @kaya3 good hint. It wasn't my intent to express that union is never assignable to intersection, updated answer.